# jboss as 7 - running multiple instances in the same linux server - standalone vs domain

Tags: configuration, jboss, installation, jboss7.x

1. I downloaded the jboss tar file.
2. Copied into my test server.
3. Did untar and installed it at $HOME/jboss/

Now, I need to have three instances running at the same time - Dev, QA, UAT - on a SINGLE server.

Is the Domain mode for this situation?
My conclusion was that it is not. That Domain mode is to manage JVMs across multiple servers. 
For example, if I wanted QA to be in server1 and server2.
Is that correct?

However, my need is NOT to manage JBOSS instances across multiple servers.

Given that should I be using standalone mode?
If so, how would I run three instances of JBOSS (Dev, QA and UAT) concurrently.

I tried the instructions given here (Approach 2) : https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MultipleInstancesOfJBossAS7OnTheSameMachine

But I keep getting the errors like this:

```
MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:9990
```

Is there any simple tutorial that I can follow.
I see this questions asked multiple times, but none of them seem to have a satisfactory answer.... that I find helpful. Is this a black art that lowly developers should not attempt in their home alone?

SGB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get multiple jboss instances running on linux, in JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml, I changed a single line from :

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
```

to the following...

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:100}">
```

NOTE:
The reason I was having problem was because I had setup my JBOSS_HOME in my .bash_profile as per the jboss installation instructions. I needed to remove this so that both instances would not use the same JBOSS_HOME.

Answer (score 5):

**Slight Change in above comment.**

bash$ ./standalone.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=**10000**

This will start the server port as **18080.**

default port is **8080 + 10000 will give 18080.**

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to add "-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000" while starting standalone.sh, e.g.:

```
./standalone.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
```

This will start jboss on ports +1000 to the standard ones (so 8080 will become 18080). No need to change xml files.

Comment: ./standalone.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=10000 will give port as 18080

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jboss on Intellij, you would like to add the offset into server configuration, just go to Run --> Edit configuration:

[image]