# JBoss 7: Standalone or domain: Run more as one (same) application on one machine

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a server on which should running several Demo Applications on JBoss. The applications are exactly the same like each other. Only the ports for the web access, used database and so on should be differ (so each customer has an separate access to his demo system). All demo applications should be running on the same machine / operating system.

Whats the best/correct way? Standalone (with different JBoss instances for each demo application; see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991529/jboss-as-7-running-multiple-instances-in-the-same-linux-server-standalone-vs))? Or the domain mode with different JBoss server/server-groups for each demo application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on if you want to manage your servers from one location (so called Domain Controller) - it will give you the ability to control all servers (hosts in this case), deploy apps and configure them from one management console. If you need this, you could benefit from Domain Mode. If not, there is no reason why you shouldn't have separated instances of JBoss in standalone mode and control them separately, both options are perfectly fine.

Comment: So I can say, that the domain mode can be also called as "cluster mode".

Comment: Well, not realy, servers in domain mode doesn't have to create cluster, you have to explicitly enable and configure this.